# Confusion in calculating the limit of a function

Tags: limits, functions, continuity

There was this question in my coaching material which kind of confused me. This was the question asked

> [image]
> and the question further asked whether the function is continuous at x = 0 or not.

my attempt was that I tried solving the right hand limit and left hand limit separately ad used the relation that **for all positive real values of x**
$$sinx < x$$
and thus the right hand limit at x=0 is 1.

**And also for all negative real values of x** , we have
$$sinx > x$$

and thus the left hand limit is 2 .

And thus the limit should not exist but the answer says that the limit exists but the function is discontinuous.

Now I have no clue how to fix it. My friend said that since the function $\frac{sinx}{x}$ is even , so you don't need to solve both the limits and just go on with the right hand limit but this is not an explanation which I needed since calculating the right hand limit and the left hand limit separately is the most basic step in finding the limit.

So i am here in search of a satisfactory answer. Please help me with my problem.

Comment: The first two terms of the alternating series, the Taylor Series for $\sin(x)$ is given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Trigonometric_functions).  You can conclude from this that as $x \to 0^+$, although $\frac{\sin(x)}{x} \to 1$, you will have that $$\left\lfloor \frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right\rfloor = 0.$$  You draw the same conclusion if $x \to 0^-$.

Comment: @user2661923 hmm ..  but what's wrong with my approach ?

Comment: Re previous comment, this implies that as $x \to 0$, you have that $$\left\lfloor \frac{2\sin(x)}{x}\right\rfloor = 1.$$

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, both the right hand limit and left hand limit equal $1$.  So, the right hand and left hand limits are the same, but the function is not continuous at $x = 0$.  This is because $2$ is not equal to $1$.

Comment: Take a closer look at the Taylor Series.  Note that if you have a convergent alternating series, that looks like $a_1 - a_2 + a_3 - a_4 + \cdots - \cdots $, where $a_n$ is strictly decreasing and going towards $0$, then you have that the series must converge to some value strictly between $a_1$ and $(a_1 - a_2)$.

Comment: This implies that regardless of whether $x$ is positive or negative, for $x$ close to $0$, you have that $(1/2) < \frac{\sin(x)}{x} < 1.$